# How to convert specific string or numbers into desired list by using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I need to convert the input into desired output by using python.

The rule is to match all the indices with the numbers of the each second row. and if the size is larger or equal to 10, then the number needs 1 extra space per 10 numbers. (ex. if the size is 025, 2 spaces for 2 times) FYI, the numbers inside '[]' are hexadecimal format.

The input and desired output are shown as below:

<input.txt>

```
[00], idx=06, size=001
[06000] 00
[01], idx=07, size=001
[07000] 00
[02], idx=20, size=007
[20000] 00 00 00 00 40 00 00
[03], idx=33, size=002
[33000] 2b 03
[04], idx=45, size=015
[45000] ff 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
[4500a] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[45014] 00 00 00 00 00
```

<output.txt>

```
[index]06 00
[index]07 00
[index]20 00 00 00 00 40 00 00
[index]33 2b 03
[index]45 ff 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00
```

In order to achieve the goal, There are the steps I came up with.

1. put [index] on beginning of every line.
2. list all the numbers that matches with 'idx'
3. extend the numbers of the second rows of index.

and I've managed to do the following so far:

```
import sys,os,re

def get_index(f):
    for line in f.readlines():
        if "idx" in line:
            yield line[10:12]

def main():
    with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
        with open("output.txt", "w") as oup:
            for line in get_index(f):
                oup.write('[index]' + line + '\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

for me, step 3 seems to be hard.. How can I develop it from here?
Or any better idea to solve this? Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Comment: In the first four examples (`[00],[01],[02],[03]`), the size is the same as the number of elements in each second row after `[idx]`. In your last example, at `45000` you have 10 bytes, at `4500a` you have 10 bytes, and at `45014`  you have 5 bytes. However the size on line `[04]` is 15, and in the desired output you indeed report 15 bytes. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: @Fra93 Yes That's correct

Comment: This is not related to the solution itself, but you want to use `yield` while reading files to not read all of them at the same time hence filling up your memory. However, the way you have implemented it is useless because you read all of the file anyway with `readlines`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a 2-step process.

Consume the file building a dictionary of the data you're interested in.

Use *re* to isolate the idx and size values rather than fixed offsets.

Once you have the data in a manageable structure, you can then work through the dictionary to generate the required output.

Here's one way of doing it:

```
import re

INFILE = 'input.txt'
OUTFILE = 'output.txt'

result = dict()
key = None

with open(INFILE) as txt:
    for line in map(str.strip, txt):
        if (found := re.findall(r'idx=(\d+).*size=(\d+).*', line)):
            key, size = found[0]
            result[key] = [int(size)]
        else:
            result[key].extend(line.split()[1:])

output = []

for k, v in result.items():
    output.append(f'[index]{k}')
    size, hexvals = v[0], v[1:]
    for i in range(0, size, 10):
        output[-1] += ' ' if i == 0 else '  '
        output[-1] += ' '.join(hexvals[i:min(i+10, size)])

with open(OUTFILE, 'w') as outfile:
    print(*output, sep='\n', file=outfile)
```

**Output (in file):**

```
[index]06 00
[index]07 00
[index]20 00 00 00 00 40 00 00
[index]33 2b 03
[index]45 ff 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90  50 00 00 00 60
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I edit the code to make the actual ouput.txt file? cus It seems to manually put '\n' to separate lines..

Comment: @Parine You will need to open a file in mode 'w' and write the output list to it

Comment: @Parine Answer edited to show you how to open a file and write to it

Comment: Okay Got u. perfect.

Comment: Just a note, consider that if the index is hex the regexp will fail. Maybe is better to match with a `[0-9a-fA-F]+`

Comment: @Fra93 I see nothing in the question to suggest that the size might be expressed as haxdecimal. Maybe I missed something

Comment: @OldBill thanks for the answer, I was referring to the index, not the size. The question says "FYI, the numbers inside '[]' are hexadecimal format."

Comment: The values inside square brackets in the input are irrelevant as they are not required in the output

Comment: @OldBill if idx is indeed hex, your code does not work because the regexp fails to match.

Comment: @Fra93 idx is not inside square brackets and is therefore assumed not to be hexadecimal. Please re-read the question

Comment: My bad :) You are right!

Comment: Both of u made good points thanks:)

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer is very good, they were faster than me but I though it would be good to post my solution as well :)

The solution is pretty similar when using a regexp to get what I call the `status line` which gives information on how much data retrieve from the subsequent lines.

- First we find where the status lines are and get their indexes.
- We start then at these indexes and we walk down to retrieve the data.
- We use a regexp to retrieve the data, defined in a regexp as [`\d`] separated by a whitespace.
- We iterate over this data until the data is completed or the size has been reached.

For the sake of testing I used strings instead of files,so you can test is also in an online python editor.

```
import re

in_file = """[00], idx=06, size=001
[06000] 00
[01], idx=07, size=001
[07000] 00
[02], idx=20, size=007
[20000] 00 00 00 00 40 00 00
[03], idx=33, size=002
[33000] 2b 03
[04], idx=45, size=015
[45000] ff 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
[4500a] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[45014] 00 00 00 00 00"""

out_file = ""

# same as open(f).readlines()
lines = in_file.split("\n")

# This regexp matches with the lines that contain status command like [00], idx=06, size=001
rstatus = re.compile(r"\[[0-9a-fA-F]+\],\s+idx=([0-9a-fA-F]+),\s+size=(\d+)")
rdata   = re.compile(r"\[[0-9a-fA-F]+\]\s+(.*)")    

# Find all the indexes of these status lines
status_indexes = [ i for i,line in enumerate(lines) if rstatus.match(line) != None ]

# Now use the index as a starting point and walk down the line
for si in status_indexes:
    
    # Get the status line
    line = lines[si]
    
    # Match idx and size
    status_match = rstatus.match(line)
    idx  = str(status_match.group(1)) #index is hex
    size = int(status_match.group(2))
    
    # Iterate until the size is consumed
    out_file += "[index] "
    out_file += f"[{str(idx)}]"
    
    offset = si+1
    while(size > 0):
        
        # Get data from the next lines
        dline = lines[offset] 
        data  = rdata.match(dline).group(1).split(" ")
        
        for d in data:
            out_file += d + " "
            size -= 1
            
            if size == 0:
                break
            
        offset += 1
        
    out_file += '\n'

print(out_file)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't produce the desired output - e.g., [index] [69]ff 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00. There is no index 69. Also, if the size values are indeed hexadecimal (change size=015 to size=00F for example) the behaviour is quite wrong

Comment: @OldBill thanks, I fixed it by treating the index as a string. The size is not hex, as per OP statement only indexes are, so I didn't cover that case.

Comment: You may want to re-read the question and also wonder why my answer has been selected as being correct and yours hasn't

Comment: Pedantic but not petty. I have lost count of the number of times I've been criticised for not producing the **exact** output required in a question. I'm inclined to delete my answer due to its obvious failings but for some unknown reason it's been accepted - so I can't